# spilt columns twice using Python

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have a large dataset (4GB) like this:

```
            userID   date   timeofday   seq
0   1000014754    20211028         20  133669542676:1:148;133658378700:1:16;133650937891:1:85
1   1000019906    20211028          6  508420199:0:0;133669581685:1:19
2   1000019906    20211028         22  133665269544:0:0
```

From this, I would like to split "seq" by ";" first and create a new dataset with renames. It looks like this:

```
            userID   date   timeofday   seq1      seq2  seq3 ... seqN
0   1000014754    20211028         20  133669542676:1:148 133658378700:1:16 133650937891:1:85
1   1000019906    20211028          6  508420199:0:0 133669581685:1:19 None None
2   1000019906    20211028         22  133665269544:0:0 None None None
```

Then I want to split the seq1,seq2,...,seqN by ":", and create a new dataset with renames. It looks like this:

```
            userID   date   timeofday   name1  click1  time1 name2 click2 time2 ....nameN clickN timeN
0   1000014754    20211028         20  133669542676 1 148 133658378700 1 16 133650937891 1 85 None None None
1   1000019906    20211028          6  508420199 0 0 133669581685 1 19 None None None None None None
2   1000019906    20211028         22  133665269544 0 0 None None None None None None None None None
```

I know pandas.split can split the columns, but I don't know how to split it effficiently. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A clean solution is to use a regex and `extractall`, then reshape using `unstack`, rename the columns and `join` to the original dataframe.

Assuming `df` the dataframe name

```
df2 = (df['seq'].str.extractall(r'(?P<name>[^:]+):(?P<click>[^:]+):(?P<time>[^;]+);?')
         .unstack('match')
         .sort_index(level=1, axis=1, sort_remaining=False)
       )
df2.columns = df2.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}{x[1]+1}')
df2 = df.drop(columns='seq').join(df2)
```

output:

```
       userID      date  timeofday         name1 click1 time1         name2 click2 time2         name3 click3 time3
0  1000014754  20211028         20  133669542676      1   148  133658378700      1    16  133650937891      1    85
1  1000019906  20211028          6     508420199      0     0  133669581685      1    19           NaN    NaN   NaN
2  1000019906  20211028         22  133665269544      0     0           NaN    NaN   NaN           NaN    NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should get you the result:

```
A = pd.DataFrame({1:[2,3,4], 2:['as:d', 'asd', 'a:sd']})
print(A)
for i in A.index:
    split =str(A[2][i]).split(':',1)
    A.at[i,3] = split[0]
    if len(split) > 1:
        A.at[i, 4] = split[1]
print(A)
```

It's probably slow since the dataframe is updated often. Alternatively you can write the new columns in separate lists and merge them into one table later.2